# iOS App crashes after restoring simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, xcode4.5, sigabrt

### Before my problem

I was creating an app for iPhone and, after taking my first snapshot, when I ran it on the simulator the storyboard changes in any view where not shown, but all the code changes were applied correctly. I don't know how to solve it but now I have a worse problem. In order to fix the "storyboard changes update" thing **I restored the simulator** (Resetting contents and settings).

### My problem

**Now, when I launch the app I get the SIGABRT error.**

### What I did

I have already restarted the computer, the simulator and Xcode. I also did the Clean thing [cmd + shift + K] and the Clean Build Folder thing [option + cmd + shift + K]. I did all together.

Not working already.

Sometimes I start Xcode and the run button is greyed out but still works.

#### Some not valid solution

I restored the previous files in the *~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications* and the application worked again (Storyboard changes not updating, of course) but I want my simulator restored, not some trick.

**Note:**
The old app folder in the simulator was *984E5409-2F65-4560-8AE3-59CDEAC3F314*
The new one has a different name, but I don't know if this is the cause.

Thank you very much.

---

**Edited:**

All the problems begin when I created a snapshot of the app because I was starting major changes. Could the simulator be trying to load the snapshot? That would explain why it's crashing after resetting the simulator and why the changes in the view where not shown.

Comment: Did you try resetting the contents and settings option in simulator and then clean and build xcode?

Comment: Yes, is after doing that when my Simulator stops working. I missed a word in the description. Sorry.

Comment: I think that resetting the simulator is what makes everything going bad.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar... Try opening the first few xib files your app touches on startup and making "dummy" changes to them, then saving (to force the xib to be rewritten from the internal representation).

Comment: I'm using a storyboard instead of XIB files. I change things on it as a button title and still not working.

Comment: Something strange also happen.

If I add the old working folder (984E5409-2F65-4560-8AE3-59CDEAC3F314) to the Applications folder without deleting the new one (39664DA6-5DEF-402A-84B8-449C8589E0DF) it works. It seems that is referencing to that old folder or something...

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator.

Comment: I did it. It's done when resetting the simulator but I did it again and still no work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the application was unchecked under the "Target Membership", in the File Inspector.

I checked it and everything get solved. For some reason it changed in some files when doing the snapshot.

[image: Target Membership]

Thanks all of you.